# How to Access wcf rest service Messagecontract from android

Tags: android, wcf, http-post

i am using wcf rest service to upload files from android.i created a service like below and i want to send fileName and filebody from android but i am not able to send filename and filebody from android.

**WCF Rest SERVICE:**

```
 public interface IService1
    {

        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "upload")]
        // string PostImage(Stream stream);
        string PostImage(ResponseFile file);
    }

    [MessageContract]
    public class ResponseFile : IDisposable
    {
        [MessageHeader]
        public string Filename;

        [MessageBodyMember]
        public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (FileByteStream != null)
            {
                FileByteStream.Close();
                FileByteStream = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Android Code to consume wcf rest service:**

```
  httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.34/Service1.svc/upload");
                        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 9000000);
                        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 9000000);
                        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                                new FileInputStream(new File(picturePath)), -1);


                        reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
                        reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed

                       httppost.setHeader("Filename", picturePath);
                        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
                        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

how can i set messageheader and messagebody from android client.can you please help me out in solving this problem. and also how can i enquire content range from server to android client.

Comment: You probably need to get the WSDL from the web service to know what the XML structure is that you'll use to pass the Message Contract from your device to the host. Look up svcutil.exe, the MS utility to get you started.